# how to parse json in ios using web url

Tags: ios, json

hi i getting json from an external source and parsing it in ios. my code is below

Note = json and cats variables are NSArray;

```
    NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myurl.json"];
    NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

    cats = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i=0; i < json.count; i++) {
        NSString * CatId = [[json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"id"];
        NSString * CatName = [[json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"name"];
        NSString * CatIcon = [[json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"icon"];
        categories * cat = [[categories alloc] initWithCId:CatId andCName:CatName andCIcon:CatIcon];

        [cats addObject:cat];
```

and json is here

`{"categories":[{"id":1,"name":"Healthcare","icon":"/icons/images/65/original_56.png?1386745569"},{"id":10,"name":"Mall","icon":"/icons/images/60/original_51.png?1386745369"},{"id":11,"name":"Taupheq","icon":"/icons/images/23/original_14.png?1386744595"},{"id":12,"name":"Hotel","icon":"/icons/images/27/original_18.png?1386744659"},{"id":13,"name":"SPA","icon":"/icons/images/48/original_39.png?1386745093"},{"id":14,"name":"ATM","icon":"/icons/images/22/original_13.png?1386744578"},{"id":15,"name":"Travel","icon":"/icons/images/12/original_3.png?1386744393"},{"id":16,"name":"Game zone","icon":"/icons/images/68/original_59.png?1386745626"},{"id":17,"name":"Academic","icon":"/icons/images/10/original_1.png?1386744264"},{"id":18,"name":"Textile","icon":"/icons/images/46/original_37.png?1386745050"}]}`

Comment: What did you get when you used the above code ? An empty array right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
json = [dict objectForKey:@"categories"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
     NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myurl.json"];
     NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    NSDictionary * json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
    NSArray *catsArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[json objectForKey:@"categories"]];

    cats = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i = 0; i < catsArray.count; i++) {
        NSString * CatId = [[catsArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"id"];
        NSString * CatName = [[catsArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"name"];
        NSString * CatIcon = [[catsArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"icon"];
        categories * cat = [[categories alloc] initWithCId:CatId andCName:CatName andCIcon:CatIcon];

        [cats addObject:cat];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are trying this:

```
NSString * CatId = [[json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"id"];
```

It translates into: Array -> Dictionary -> String

But you can see you dont want this.
You want: Dictionary -> Array -> Dictionary ->String

In Code:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
NSArray *array = [dict objectForKey:@"categories"];
NSString * CatId = [[array objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"id"];
```

Answer (score 0):

try this . . .

```
NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myurl.json"];
NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

NSDictionary * json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

NSArray * cat = [json objectForKey:@"categories"];

for(NSDictionary * tempdict in cat)
{
    NSString * CatId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[tempdict objectForKey:@"id"]];
    NSString * CatName = [tempdict objectForKey:@"name"];
    NSString * CatIcon = [tempdict objectForKey:@"icon"];
    categories * cat = [[categories alloc] initWithCId:CatId andCName:CatName andCIcon:CatIcon];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

THis should work : Consider the Json as NSMutableArray and then easily you ail get the array of the object one by one :

```
 NSMutableArray  *userDetails = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:returnData options:0 error:nil];
    NSLog(@"User Det %@", userDetails);
    if (userDetails == nil || [userDetails count] == 0) {

    } else {

          // 3. iterate the array; each element is a dictionary...
          for (NSDictionary *lesson in userDetails)
          {

             NSString * CatId = [[catsArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"id"];
             NSString * CatName = [[catsArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"name"];
             NSString * CatIcon = [[catsArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"icon"];
             categories * cat = [[categories alloc] initWithCId:CatId andCName:CatName andCIcon:CatIcon];
             [cats addObject:cat];
           }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myurl.json"];
    NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    NSDictionary *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

    NSArray *myArray = [jsonData objectForKey:@"categories"];

    cats = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (NSDictionary *temp in myArray) {

        NSString * CatId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[temp objectForKey:@"id"]];
        NSString * CatName = [temp objectForKey:@"name"];
        NSString * CatIcon = [temp objectForKey:@"icon"];
        categories * cat = [[categories alloc] initWithCId:CatId andCName:CatName andCIcon:CatIcon];

        [cats addObject:cat];
   }
```